# azure account import command - mac - what gives?

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I am trying to import my .publishsettings file and I keep getting the same error. I have tried every variation I can think of and still can't get the file imported. Please help!

Here is the basic command I'm using and error I receive:

```
   $ azure account import /Users/username-2-12-2015-credentials.publishsettings
info:    Executing command account import
error:   ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/myDir/Users/username-2-12-2015-credentials.publishsettings'
info:    Error information has been recorded to /home/myDir/.azure/azure.err
error:   account import command failed
```

I got this file using the `azure account download` command as outlined in http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/

No idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I realize it's an obvious question, but... Are you sure your path to the publishsettings file is correct?

Comment: Well, I tried putting the file in several locations to see if maybe there where issues with how I was calling the path. Let's say it was on my desktop. I was using `/User/myDirectory/Desktop/username-2-12-2015-credentials.publishsettings` I would always receive the same error.

Comment: I meant, are you actually typing the right directory name? In your comment, you say `/User/...`. Is that really the root folder name? Not `/Users` ? And in your original question, you reference `/Users/mydirectory` - shouldn't there be a user folder as well? That's what I'm asking: Are you sure you're properly specifying the directory? All your examples seem like they're pointing to the wrong place. (of course, maybe you're just shorthanding your posts here...)

Comment: sorry, yes, i did shorthand my post and replaced my actual name path with a generic version. I think i messed up in my original post, but the path is correct in the sense that what I specified as my path is how the path appears on a mac. I'm not sure if it needs to be specified differently on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the file name had anything to do with it, but I renamed it to `creds.publishsettings`

Then this was my import command:

`azure account import ~/Downloads/creds.publishsettings`

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the downloaded file to anything XYZ. And try the command, it works. Strange!